# Strange encoding behaviour in AFNetworking

Tags: php, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking in and iOS project and so far everything went ok. Now I have a script in PHP that is supposed to get some info and return some json. Both the info the script is provided with and the json it is supposed to return cointains latin chars, mainly ã and õ.

The thing is that when i recieve the json back at my iOS app the characters come encoded as what I think is NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding. I think the encoding is not UTF8 because back at the app:

```
    [jsonManager GET:myURL parameters:sendingData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op,id responseObject){


    NSLog(@"%d",op.responseStringEncoding);
    NSLog(@"%d",op.responseSerializer.stringEncoding);
    NSLog(@"%@",op.responseString);
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:op.responseData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op,NSError *error){

    NSLog(@"%@",op.responseString);


}];
```

The last NSLog(in case of success) is the only one that outputs the responseString as it was supposed to be. The third log outputs \u00e3 in the place of every ã.
And the first log confirms that the encoding used was NSUTF8StringEncoding.
The second log states that responseSerializer.stringEnconding is NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding because I set it to be like that, previously to making the request, it made no difference, dont know why either...

The really strange thing is that if I invoke the script using a browser I can see that the output is encoded as UTF8.

What is wrong here?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your server is using different encoding types depending on the client or some header.

NSJSONSerialization strictly implements [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), which states:

> JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
>      UTF-8.

JSON is always Unicode-encoded, so my guess is that your server isn't following the spec.

Instead of using your browser, try to replicate the behavior using CURL, or a Chrome plug-in like [Advanced REST Client](http://chromerestclient.appspot.com/).  One place to start is your server's parsing of the `Accept`, `User-Agent` and `Content-Type` headers.